# python i2c smbus erro, data sending

Tags: python, i2c, smbus

here is an programe from github https://github.com/karabek/OrangePi-OLED/blob/master/oled/device.py , it's for sending data to i2c oled device. I'm trying to make it work on my system. I changed the program a litle bit to let it work on port 3 and print the data send so I can check the erro in data.
here is the program after edit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# The MIT License (MIT)
#
# Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Hull
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.


# Example usage:
#
#   from oled.device import ssd1306, sh1106
#   from oled.render import canvas
#   from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw
#
#   font = ImageFont.load_default()
#   device = sh1106(port=1, address=0x3C)
#
#   with canvas(device) as draw:
#      draw.rectangle((0, 0, device.width, device.height), outline=0, fill=0)
#      draw.text(30, 40, "Hello World", font=font, fill=255)
#
# As soon as the with-block scope level is complete, the graphics primitives
# will be flushed to the device.
#
# Creating a new canvas is effectively 'carte blanche': If you want to retain
# an existing canvas, then make a reference like:
#
#    c = canvas(device)
#    for X in ...:
#        with c as draw:
#            draw.rectangle(...)
#
# As before, as soon as the with block completes, the canvas buffer is flushed
# to the device

import smbus


class device(object):
    """
    Base class for OLED driver classes
    """

    def __init__(self, port=3, address=0x3C, cmd_mode=0x00, data_mode=0x40):
        self.cmd_mode = cmd_mode
        self.data_mode = data_mode
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(port)
        self.addr = address

    def command(self, *cmd):
        """
        Sends a command or sequence of commands through to the
        device - maximum allowed is 32 bytes in one go.
        """
        assert(len(cmd) <= 32)
        print(cmd)
        self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.addr, self.cmd_mode, list(cmd))

    def data(self, data):
        """
        Sends a data byte or sequence of data bytes through to the
        device - maximum allowed in one transaction is 32 bytes, so if
        data is larger than this it is sent in chunks.
        """
        for i in xrange(0, len(data), 32):
            self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.addr,
                                          self.data_mode,
                                          list(data[i:i+32]))


class sh1106(device):
    """
    A device encapsulates the I2C connection (address/port) to the SH1106
    OLED display hardware. The init method pumps commands to the display
    to properly initialize it. Further control commands can then be
    called to affect the brightness. Direct use of the command() and
    data() methods are discouraged.
    """

    def __init__(self, port=1, address=0x3C):
        super(sh1106, self).__init__(port, address)
        self.width = 128
        self.height = 64
        self.pages = self.height / 8

        self.command(
            const.DISPLAYOFF,
            const.MEMORYMODE,
            const.SETHIGHCOLUMN,      0xB0, 0xC8,
            const.SETLOWCOLUMN,       0x10, 0x40,
            const.SETCONTRAST,        0x7F,
            const.SETSEGMENTREMAP,
            const.NORMALDISPLAY,
            const.SETMULTIPLEX,       0x3F,
            const.DISPLAYALLON_RESUME,
            const.SETDISPLAYOFFSET,   0x00,
            const.SETDISPLAYCLOCKDIV, 0xF0,
            const.SETPRECHARGE,       0x22,
            const.SETCOMPINS,         0x12,
            const.SETVCOMDETECT,      0x20,
            const.CHARGEPUMP,         0x14,
            const.DISPLAYON)

    def display(self, image):
        """
        Takes a 1-bit image and dumps it to the SH1106 OLED display.
        """
        assert(image.mode == '1')
        assert(image.size[0] == self.width)
        assert(image.size[1] == self.height)

        page = 0xB0
        pix = list(image.getdata())
        step = self.width * 8
        for y in xrange(0, self.pages * step, step):

            # move to given page, then reset the column address
            self.command(page, 0x02, 0x10)
            page += 1

            buf = []
            for x in xrange(self.width):
                byte = 0
                for n in xrange(0, step, self.width):
                    byte |= (pix[x + y + n] & 0x01) << 8
                    byte >>= 1

                buf.append(byte)

            self.data(buf)


class ssd1306(device):
    """
    A device encapsulates the I2C connection (address/port) to the SSD1306
    OLED display hardware. The init method pumps commands to the display
    to properly initialize it. Further control commands can then be
    called to affect the brightness. Direct use of the command() and
    data() methods are discouraged.
    """
    def __init__(self, port=1, address=0x3C):
        super(ssd1306, self).__init__(port, address)
        self.width = 128
        self.height = 64
        self.pages = self.height / 8

        self.command(
            const.DISPLAYOFF,
            const.SETDISPLAYCLOCKDIV, 0x80,
            const.SETMULTIPLEX,       0x3F,
            const.SETDISPLAYOFFSET,   0x00,
            const.SETSTARTLINE,
            const.CHARGEPUMP,         0x14,
            const.MEMORYMODE,         0x00,
            const.SEGREMAP,
            const.COMSCANDEC,
            const.SETCOMPINS,         0x12,
            const.SETCONTRAST,        0xCF,
            const.SETPRECHARGE,       0xF1,
            const.SETVCOMDETECT,      0x40,
            const.DISPLAYALLON_RESUME,
            const.NORMALDISPLAY,
            const.DISPLAYON)

    def display(self, image):
        """
        Takes a 1-bit image and dumps it to the SSD1306 OLED display.
        """
        assert(image.mode == '1')
        assert(image.size[0] == self.width)
        assert(image.size[1] == self.height)

        self.command(
            const.COLUMNADDR, 0x00, self.width-1,  # Column start/end address
            const.PAGEADDR,   0x00, self.pages-1)  # Page start/end address

        pix = list(image.getdata())
        step = self.width * 8
        buf = []
        for y in xrange(0, self.pages * step, step):
            i = y + self.width-1
            while i >= y:
                byte = 0
                for n in xrange(0, step, self.width):
                    byte |= (pix[i + n] & 0x01) << 8
                    byte >>= 1

                buf.append(byte)
                i -= 1

        self.data(buf)


class const:
    CHARGEPUMP = 0x8D
    COLUMNADDR = 0x21
    COMSCANDEC = 0xC8
    COMSCANINC = 0xC0
    DISPLAYALLON = 0xA5
    DISPLAYALLON_RESUME = 0xA4
    DISPLAYOFF = 0xAE
    DISPLAYON = 0xAF
    EXTERNALVCC = 0x1
    INVERTDISPLAY = 0xA7
    MEMORYMODE = 0x20
    NORMALDISPLAY = 0xA6
    PAGEADDR = 0x22
    SEGREMAP = 0xA0
    SETCOMPINS = 0xDA
    SETCONTRAST = 0x81
    SETDISPLAYCLOCKDIV = 0xD5
    SETDISPLAYOFFSET = 0xD3
    SETHIGHCOLUMN = 0x10
    SETLOWCOLUMN = 0x00
    SETMULTIPLEX = 0xA8
    SETPRECHARGE = 0xD9
    SETSEGMENTREMAP = 0xA1
    SETSTARTLINE = 0x40
    SETVCOMDETECT = 0xDB
    SWITCHCAPVCC = 0x2
```

and then it give an erro:

```
(174, 213, 128, 168, 63, 211, 0, 64, 141, 20, 32, 0, 160, 200, 218, 18, 129, 207, 217, 241, 219, 64, 164, 166, 175)
(33, 0, 127, 34, 0, 7.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/OrangePi-OLED/gui.py", line 8, in <module>
    with canvas(device) as draw:
  File "/root/OrangePi-OLED/oled/render.py", line 74, in __exit__
    self.device.display(self.image)
  File "/root/OrangePi-OLED/oled/device.py", line 190, in display
    self.command(
  File "/root/OrangePi-OLED/oled/device.py", line 74, in command
    self.bus.write_i2c_block_data(self.addr, self.cmd_mode, list(cmd))
TypeError: Third argument must be a list of at least one, but not more than 32 integers
```

I don't understand this, with the data print Third argument is 31 integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(174, 213, 128, 168, 63, 211, 0, 64, 141, 20, 32, 0, 160, 200, 218, 18, 129, 207, 217, 241, 219, 64, 164, 166, 175)
(33, 0, 127, 34, 0, 7.0)
```

Your `device.command()` ran twice as there are two lines of output here. It looks like the first one succeeded. It's the second one that failed. The last element in that tuple is `7.0` which is not an integer. It looks like that comes from

`self.pages = self.height / 8`

Python division returns a float, not an integer. Try casting the result to an `int`:

`self.pages = int(self.height / 8)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the amount of data, it's the data type, there is a float

Use a for loop to int all the data:

```
cmd_int = list(cmd)
for i in range(0, len(cmd_int)):
    cmd_int[i]=int(cmd_int[i])
    i = i+1
```